# How do I use Opensocial's gadgets.io?

Tags: javascript, web, opensocial

After browsing through API's on a few sites, I figured I'd ask - I just want to know how to import it. Is it a javascript file that I can download and include on my site? Is there a link to it? All the examples show what you can do with this makeRequest() function but I can't find anything that tells you how to get said function.

Answer (score 0):

Gadgets.io is not something that can be included in any old web app.  It is intended to be used within an OpenSocial gadget running inside an OpenSocial container.  The container will provide the gadgets.io namespace to the gadget when it is rendered.